# Android studio logcat support for sinhala unicode

Tags: android, unicode, logcat

I am working on an android app which works with sinhala Unicode, and im unable to make the logcat display the unicodes clearly. In the earlier version of android studio I was able to make it work by restarting a few times, but with the 3.1.2(stable) build I'm unable to see sinhala unicode almost all the time.
I hope someone has the answer for this, as getting the text to display here is really important for me. 
Thanks
[the text appears as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFnI6.png)

Comment: if you found any solution please share it.